# Cheap and cheerful "fullscreen" of a window

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen

I have a windows forms application with a tree view on the left and a control docked full on the right.  When a user clicks one of the toolbar buttons, I would like the right-side control to go "fullscreen".

Is there a quick and easy way to do this that will work on 7, 8 and XP?

Comment: Can't you change the value of the Dock property on the Forms controls? Assuming these are all on the same form that is.

Comment: Well, the control is embedded in a User Control and the User Control is docked inside a panel, and the panel is on a form.  So it's not quite so simple :).  I just thought there might be a quick and easy way of doing it.

Comment: Is it your user control or a third party?

Comment: Its a bit nasty but you could implement an event in the UserControl that changes the Dock values of it's controls then set the UserControl Dock to Fill. Other than that I would recommend having a separate control on your Form that is displayed when required then hidden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make UserControl fullscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128008/make-usercontrol-fullscreen)

Comment: OK this seemed to work nicely.  Created a new windowless full-screen form and moved the control to it, moving it back when I'm done.  No drama :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128008/make-usercontrol-fullscreen